# How to obtain a text against a checkbox. I have to tick the Checkbox and have to get the text against that Checkbox

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have tried this code and its not working. It is showing null.

```
String ServiceName = SitePackageScript.driver.findElement(By.xpath("xxxxxx")).getAttribute("Value");
```

The HTML

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=chkservice_0</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please post the html of the checkbox.

Comment: <tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>id=chkservice_0</td>
 <td></td>
    </tr>

Comment: There is no text in the html.

Comment: A Text is given against that. Not in the Checkbox. Like listing.

Comment: No one can help here without the relevant html.

Comment: Html for the Checkbox is given in the above comment. It is actually a listing like, consider the number as checkbox..1  Text. I have to get that "Text". Anywat I can get that?

Comment: Please put all relevant information to the question in the question... HTML, code, etc. so that everyone is more likely to see it and it can be properly formatted.

Comment: The HTML you posted is not valid HTML. Are you sure it's correct? The id is not even inside a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use "value" instead of "Value"

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xxxxxx")).getText();
```

Comment: The xpath is that of a check box. So it will not give any text. I need the Text which has been written against a check box.

Comment: in your sample html code, there is not any input/checkbox element. also, check box doesn't have a text, most probably another element near to it have text. so, where exactly you want to get text?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Checkbox element doesn't have any text in that. The element next to it contains the text and i need to take the text.

Comment: your html doesn't provide enough data. please share more information or html code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using driver.findElement(), try using driver.findElements() as this.

```
 List<WebElement> CHECKBOXlist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpathofcheckbox"));
for(WebElement checkbox : CHECKBOXlist)

  {
     System.out.println(checkbox.getText());
     checkbox.click();
 }
```